# Why does my website shift to the left on Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: Screenshot of My Website on Safari]

You are able to visit my website at [here](http://icastem.prasetiyamulya.ac.id/)

This happens when I add this CSS styling:

```
.container {
  margin-inline: auto;
  width: min(90%, 70.5rem);
}
```

The reason i add this container is to restrict my contents from expanding when someone opens the website in a very large screen. This works fine with other browsers. Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: its working fine for me in safari too..

Comment: Is it a devops website? :p

Comment: Refer to using `margin: 0 auto` as `margin-inline` has limited browser support.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Safari browser v14.0 and below does not support `margin-inline`

[image]

Try to use `margin: 0 auto`

For more details visit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline

Comment: Please follow the formatting rules in https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Comment: @BoltClock I did follow the referencing guidelines

Comment: You didn't indicate which portion of the text came from the link - namely the first paragraph, nowhere near where the link actually is. It's not formatted as a quote, so it just looks like something you wrote yourself.

Answer (score 2):

`margin-inline` is not supported by Safari, IOS Safari or Edge see so it probably isn't safe to rely on it given the ubiquity of Safari and the increasing use of Edge.

See https://caniuse.com/?search=margin-inline

Some other way of centering things on large screens will need to be used. Perhaps the more traditional left: 50% and transform: translateX(-50%) would help?